# How do I convert a JSON file into a list in Python?

Tags: python, json, xml, list, dictionary

I need to convert a JSON file stored in a dictionary into a list of dictionaries.

An example of my JSON file -

```
[{{"Alpha":"1","Bravo":"2","Charlie":"2","Delta": "4"}, {"Echo" : "5", 'Foxtrot" : "6"}}]
```

I want to output to be

```
[{"Alpha":"1","Bravo":"2","Charlie":"2","Delta": "4"}, {"Echo" : "5", 'Foxtrot" : "6"}]
```

This is just an example file, as my actual file has multiple dictionaries and many, many more keys in each dictionary.

I apologize if this is a 'noob' question as I am new to Python and coding in general.

Here is my code -

```
import json
with open('json_products.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)

    sorted_list = []
    brackets = 0
    temp_string  = ''
    string_json = (json.dumps(d, sort_keys=False, ))
    #print(string_json)

    while True:
        for i in range(len(string_json)):
            if string_json[i] == '{':
                brackets +=1
            if string_json[i] == '}':
                brackets -= 1
                temp_string = temp_string + string_json[i]
                i += 1
            if brackets == 0:
                sorted_list.append(temp_string)
                temp_string = ''
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure that first example is not valid JSON.

Comment: A JSON file can only contain one object or array. You can nest objects and arrays, but you can't have extra objects sequentially.

Comment: If I may suggest, https://jsonlint.com/ is a great way to validate your JSON online.